# JQuery ui Tabs & Autocomplete combobox nesting

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery ui tabs 
Inside a tab i want to inset an autocomplete combobox
When the combobox is outside the tabs it works perfect, but when inside the tabs it doesnt look good. 
Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please add an excerpt of the original faulty code, so the community can learn from this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it. i had a class for span inside the tabs ( #tabs span {......} ) –